# How to convert ProfilePictureView to Bitmap on xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I was able to integrate facebook auth on my xamarin application
and manage to get facebook image to a profileimageview and other information like name and email.

I have checked that there is an existing thread like and tried the solution from there however the method from it
is not working anymore at API 26

here is the method

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)pic.getChildAt(0);
    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    image_ = convertImageToByte(bmp);
```

Base on documentation getDrawable() has been depreciated at api22

is there any other work around to sort this?

My goal is to get bitmap from it and save it as base64 string to firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the following code

```
ImageView imageView =new ImageView(this);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.Drawable).Bitmap as Bitmap;
MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();

bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, baos);
byte[] imageInByte = baos.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Lucas Zhang, your amazing man! This works perfectly what i expected! You save me from a days of work.